# Run windows services with different network credentials

Tags: active-directory, service, dmz

I have server (W2016) in DMZ, not in domain. And I need start windows services (Dynamics NAV third party application) under local account but with different network credential (domain account) for SQL connection and validating users by kerberos. Application I can run with command
`runas /netonly /user:domain\username "C:\...\application.exe"`

Is it possible run windows services like runas?? Or another idea? Or general, what is best practicies for connect DMZ server (accesible from internet - not in domain) with backend servers (SQL, DC - in domain). Safety solution =)

Thanks
Zdenek

Answer (score 0):

Nothing prevents you from manipulating services with the same syntax:

```
Runas /user:Domain\username "sc \\remoteServer start ServiceKeyNameYouNeedToStart"
```

Alternatively, you can try Psexec.

-or-

Via powershell:

```
(get-wmiobject win32_service -comp ServerName -cred domain\username -filter "name='ServiceToBeTerminated'").stopservice()
```